# getUser method returns 0 when first time accessed in mozilla but works fine in chrome

Tags: php, facebook

I used following code to check user is logged in or not in FB and then redirect accordingly to my website pages.

```
include_once "./fbsrc/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

I placed above code to one file. Now I used this file to get id of user if I get id then I redirect user to page1.php and if not to page2.php as following

```
include "fbmain.php";

if(isset($uid) && !empty($uid))
{
    //redirect to page1.php  
}
else
{
    //redirect to page2.php
}
```

This code works fine in google chrome but it give problem in mozilla. In mozilla everytime user is redirect to page2.php even user is logged in FB as $uid is not set. I get int(0) when var_dump($uid). What's wrong with code. Please help me.

Thanks...

Comment: did you solve this by any chnace?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cookies disabled in Firefox?

Comment: @user392406: You should try it with them enabled then?

Comment: I means to say cookies are enabled.